# AngularJS ng-repeat only show specify key value

Tags: angularjs

My data structure is:

```
{"code":"AAA","name":"AAA industries","date":null}
```

I am trying to display just the name in a button. I am trying to use the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in company.details">
    <button ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
        {{val}}
    </button>
</div>
```

but of course that displays everything. What's my next step here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

check for key, if it is equal to name then display else dont

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in company.details">
        <button ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
            <span ng-if="key=='name'">{{val}}</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sayujo/3/edit?html,js,output) illustrating an answer.

The code logic is as follows:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kolban is correct. So in your case the answer would be:

`<div ng-repeat="item in company.details">
    {{item.val}}
</div>`